# Отфильтровать DataFrame по значениям столбца в другом DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Есть `df1` c 10k значениями и `df2` с 15к значениями. У них есть только один общий столбец `id`. Нужно обрезать df2 так, чтобы он содержал только такие значения `id`, которые содержатся в `df1`. Запутался с iloc'ами и np.where'ами.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Наиболее идиоматичным решением будет использование метода [Series.isin(other)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html)

Пример:

```
In [7]: df1
Out[7]:
   id  a  b
0   1  1  1
1   2  2  2
2   3  3  3
3   4  4  4

In [8]: df2
Out[8]:
   id   c   d
0   1  11  11
1   3  33  33
2   5  55  55
3   7  77  77
4   9  99  99

In [9]: df2['id'].isin(df1['id'])
Out[9]:
0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
4    False
Name: id, dtype: bool

In [10]: df2[df2['id'].isin(df1['id'])]
Out[10]:
   id   c   d
0   1  11  11
1   3  33  33
```